# Bootstrap v3.3.5: Dropdown height not editable

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm quite new with CSS and I'm struggling trying to fix the height of a dropdown menu, and I cant find the proper CLASS or ID to edite it.

**Here is a better explanation of my problem:**

1. On the top menu I have a dropdown button (Options) and I have 4 elements:
   [image]
2. I have a breakpoint so when the window is reduced there is a diferent menu:
   [image]
3. As you can see I cant manage to display all the elements inside the dropdown button (Options), when this is expanded:
   [image]
4. Aparently the height is ok. But there is something cutting the height of the menu:
   [image]

Any ideas how to edit this dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

**FOR FUTURE READERS:**

So, I managed to fix my problem by doing this:

1. I realized that there was a boostrap elements with a max.height of 340px. I dont know why, but I was unable to find this element inside the bootstrap.css file (may be because I am quite new at this):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

2. So I just use the magic Crtl+F button to find this '340px' and Voilà!!!, I find only two elements with this height and one of them it was setting a maximum of height for this dropdown (dont know why):

   `.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {max-height: 340px}`
3. Then I just add  `.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {max-height: 700px}` to my custom .css file after the bootstrap.css file.